# Stuck Scraping with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So i'm trying to scrape a html webpage. It has novel chapters and i'm trying to get the text and store in text files to read offline. I don't have any previous experience with html or other things either. So the webpage I am trying to scrape is [this](http://wnmtl.org/chapter/324909-heavenly-wolf-valley.html). And the code i've been testing so far looks like this

`

```
import sys
import requests
import time
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def browse_and_scrape(seed_url, page_number=1):
    # Fetch the URL - We will be using this to append to images and info routes
    url_pat = re.compile(r"(http://.*\.org)")
    source_url = url_pat.search(seed_url).group(0)

   # Page_number from the argument gets formatted in the URL & Fetched
    formatted_url = seed_url.format(str(page_number))

    # print(url_pat,source_url,formatted_url)
    try:
        html_text = requests.get(formatted_url).text
        # print(html_text)
        # Prepare the soup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
        print(soup.find_all(id="chapterContent")[0]["style"])

        print(f"Now Scraping - {formatted_url}")
        # help = soup.find_all("div",class_="chapter-content text-normal")[0].text.strip().encode("ascii", "ignore").decode("ascii")

        # for node in soup.findAll("div",class_="chapter-content text-normal"):
        #     print(node)
        #     print(''.join(node.findAll(text=True)))

        # for node in soup.findAll("div"):
        # #    print(node)
        #    print(''.join(node.findAll(text=True)))   

        # help = soup.find_all("div",class_="chapter-content text-normal")[0]
        # print(''.join(help.findAll(text=True)))
        # print(help)


    except Exception as e:
        return e

    return true

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # seed_url = "http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{}.html"
    seed_url = "http://wnmtl.org/chapter/324909-heavenly-wolf-valley.html"
    # seed_url = "http://wnmtl.org/chapter/{}.html"
    print("Web scraping has begun")
    result = browse_and_scrape(seed_url)
    if result == True:
        print("Web scraping is now complete!")
    else:
        print(f"Oops, That doesn't seem right!!! - {result}")`
```

All the commented stuff are things i've been trying to rip the text from the tag. From my inspection of the developer console in the browser, all the text is in the tag with id of chapter content. My plan is to iteratively get the text, stuff it, get the link for the next page and repeat but i've been stuck for a bit now, any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of scraping each page, you can directly get the text from this API endpoint using `requests`.

```
https://api.mystorywave.com/story-wave-backend/api/v1/content/chapters/324909
```

*The last item in the above API is the chapter ID (324909).* You can navigate to chapters by giving in the chapter IDs.

The `next` and `prev` chapter IDs are present in the current chapter's API endpoint. *Have a look at the above URL in browser to understand it better.*

Here is the full recursive code that writes the text from 3 pages to a file called `novel.txt`. You may change the number of pages and other details as per your need.

```
import requests

def get_data(chapter_id, pages):
    if pages == 0:
        return
    url = 'https://api.mystorywave.com/story-wave-backend/api/v1/content/chapters/' + str(chapter_id)
    r = requests.get(url)
    x = r.json()
    pre_id = x['data']['preId']
    next_id = x['data']['nextId']
    title = x['data']['title']
    content = x['data']['content']
    chapter_title = f'\n***** Chapter: {title} *****\n'


    with open('novel.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(chapter_title)
        f.write(content + '\n')

    print(f"Chapter: '{title}' written to file.")
    
    get_data(next_id, pages-1)



curr_id = '324909'
get_data(curr_id, 3)
```

```
Chapter: 'Heavenly Wolf Valley' written to file.
Chapter: 'Leaving' written to file.
Chapter: 'Pure Fabrication' written to file.
```